# Configure alternate access via Internet to intranet web applications with HNSC

Tags: 2013, alternate-access-mapping, host-named

I'm looking for a way to configure an alternate access via Internet to the following intranet web applications having HNSCs (host named site collections):

- `https://intranet.contoso.domain`
- `https://mysite.contoso.domain`

The access should be available with the following behaviour:

- to intranet: `https://internetaccess.contoso.com/intranet`
- to mysite: `https://internetaccess.contoso.com/mysite`

What are the required configurations both on IIS and on the Alternate Access Mappings? Should I also add something to the existing web application configurations?

It should also be noted that `https://internetaccess.contoso.com` shouldn't be the entry point to either of the web applications. Instead, to access the sites/pages, should the URLs be in the form of `https://internetaccess.contoso.com/intranet/<paths of SharePoint>` or `https://internetaccess.contoso.com/<paths of SharePoint>`.

I've come across [this MSDN blog post including the part for "Host Name Site Collections with Multiple URL's and Zones"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/russmax/2013/10/31/guide-to-sharepoint-2013-host-name-site-collections/), but I'm unsure whether that applies to my case.